# distribute simulink desktop realtime model

Tags: simulink

Recently i was try to develop some simple SIMULINK model which receive UDP packet, make some calculation and return answer via other UDP port. Model work just fine, i was able to compile to EXE - no problem. 
My goal was that model to work in real time - mean 1 second in simulation to be equal to 1 second in PC. So after research i discover that block:
**Real Time Sync**
which do the trick - now my simulation is work exactly as I want. Next when I try to build project - after make all changes in settings according documentation (mainly change target to sldrt.tlc) - at end of compile process i've got this:

```
### Created Simulink Desktop Real-Time module udpTest.rxw64 
C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2017b/toolbox/sldrt/clang/win64/llvm-link-bca \ 
          -Bstatic \ 
      -o udpTest.bc \ 
      udpTest.obj rtGetInf.obj rtGetNaN.obj rt_nonfinite.obj udpTest_data.obj udpTest_tgtconn.obj sldrt_main.obj rt_sim.obj ext_svr.obj updown_sldrt.obj \ 
       \ 
       \ 
      C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2017b/toolbox/sldrt/lib/win64/imports.obj \ 
      C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2017b/toolbox/sldrt/lib/win64/sldrtlib.lib 
C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2017b/toolbox/sldrt/clang/win64/llc -mtriple=x86_64-pc-win32 -O3 -O3 -filetype=obj -o ../udpTest.rxw64 udpTest.bc
Build process completed successfully
```

As far as I understand I can load that rxw64 file in simulink in external mode and control it - all that is ok, I've done it. But is it possible to distribute that to dedicated PC?

PS: Sorry for long description, but I'm feel really confused and i want to give all details

Answer (score 1):

Case closed. The answer is that I can't distribute my model as separate application. I must set up a target PC which must be dedicated to run binary equivalent of my model. Now - going forward to search a suitable DOS-like boot setup, and maybe try in some kind of virtual PC